# Check if email exists by sending it a message

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

Some say it's impossible to verify that an email exists, but I also read it can be done by sending a message to it. So I want to verify if the email exists or not by sending it email.

Here is my code:

```
 private void email_checker()
    {
        MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
        //The email that needs to be checked
        mm.To.Add(new MailAddress(txtEmailAddress.Text, "Email Check"));
        mm.From = new MailAddress("*******@gmail.com");
        mm.Body = "Verified";
        mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mm.Subject = "Verification";
        SmtpClient smc1 = new SmtpClient();
        smc1.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smc1.Port = 587;
        smc1.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("*****@gmail.com","********");
        smc1.EnableSsl = true;
        smc1.Send(mm);
    }
```

This code is functioning, but I tried to type any random email that does not exist (it really does not exist) and the code still sends a message to it. I wanted to create a popup message that prompts whenever the message has failed to sent in that way I'll know that the email really does not exist. Or is there really no other way than sending a verification link?

Comment: *stumbled on this website that you can verify an email if it exist by sending it a message* still doesn't work, because some servers will swallowed a message without telling you the recipient doesn't exist....

Comment: Only if the domain doesn't exist you may get an error from the SMTP, but if only the user doesn't exist, the only way is by sending and then receiving another email with the corresponding error, and parsing it... Also, keep in mind that you can't do this massively as you may get banned. There are sites that let you test a set of email addresses, but I think they are not free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to see if an email exists. Remember that your code used to send an email is asking an SmtpClient to send the email. You will only get an exception if the client's server throws one. The client's server in your case is GMail. GMail doesn't fail on sending, but replies back to the sender that the email address wasn't found. Different servers behave differently. You can setup your own server to automatically retry emails or just fail silently or throw an exception, etc. Also, servers use dns so it's possible to have an intranet mail system where the email is valid to the network, but not the internet. Another thing to keep in mind is the catch all email addresses that can be setup. So the email address in question may not be valid, but caught by the catch all and then delivered  to the valid address.

So, no possible way, as of now, to validate the existence of an email address.

Comment: even if the email does not exist smtp will still send it?I was hoping that it cause an error so that I could catch it.My only option is the validation I guess.

Comment: It depends on the server that the client connects to. GMail will not error. Other servers will, just depends. If you setup your own server, you can configure it to error. Most will not error because they batch send or retry or just leave them in an "outbox" for a period of time. This is how providers, like GMail, can impose throttling or limits on the amount of emails sent.